# Upgrading QGIS and keeping configurations

Tags: qgis, upgrade

I am looking for a way to upgrade QGIS while keeping my custom configurations/settings. I refer to settings such as view, data connections and installed plugins.

Can this be achieved?

I am using QGIS 3.16 on Windows

Comment: Config are stored in a local directory awat from the install. They will be preserved.

Comment: I agree with J.R
However, where is that folder? what is the mechanism?

Comment: @yairsuari On a window installation you will find it here "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\QGIS" this folder is preserved when you update and the information it contain will be used by the updated version (this may not work for update between major version ie. 2.x to 3.x)

Answer (score 4):

All your settings are stored in your own folder, outside of the QGIS installation itself. So removing and reinstalling QGIS, these files won't be changed, it's your own settings.

It's a common "mistake" to think that reinstalling QGIS will restore a broken feature if the bug is due to a plugin for instance. Plugins and settings won't be removed when uninstalling QGIS.

You can find this folder by clicking in QGIS :

1. "Settings" menu
2. "User profiles"
3. "Open active profile folder".

This will open your file browser, located in your user directory. You might have different profiles stored.

[image: open profile folder]

User profile per operating system:

- Linux : `.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/`
- Windows : `%AppData%\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\`
- MacOS : `Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/`

Source https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html?highlight=profile#working-with-user-profiles